# How to let a user choose the hex color for an embed command? | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a embed/say command for my bot and I am unsure how to let the user choose the embed color by entering a hex color.

I have tried this:

```
@client.command(aliases=['say'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def embed(ctx):

    questions = ["Which should be the tile of the embed?",
            "What should be the description?",
            "What is the color of the embed? This should be a hex color."]

    answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('You did not answer in time. Please do it under 30 seconds next time.')
            return
        else:
            answers.append(msg.content)

    embedcolor = answers2[2]

    embed = discord.Embed(description=answers[1], title=answers[0], colour=0x(embedcolor))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And I get this error: SyntaxError: invalid hexadecimal literal

I have also tried letting the user input the hex color with the 0x in front of it to no success. I have also tried turning this user input into an integer with no success.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an invalid format, you're doing something like so

```py
>>> 0x"ff0000"
SyntaxError: Invalid hexadecimal literal
```

If you want to convert a string to a hex integer

```py
>>> int("ff0000", 16)
16711680
```

```py
embed = discord.Embed(..., colour=int(embedcolor, 16))
```